# JitsiMeetConferenceOptions() reflects error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jitsi

I implement

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions option = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions().Builder()
```

in android studio and it shows error. Here in the logcat, it shows that

> JitsiMeetConferenceOptions() has private access in ‘org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetConferenceOptions

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ()

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder().build()
```